# Display Fees details from database In Table Format

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using a website(C#) for inserting fees details for I std to V std into a database...
next i want to display in that details in next page as a table format which is mentioned below.....

ClassName   Class I   ClassII   ClassIII   ClassIV   ClassV

TutionFees    1000      1000      1100        1100     1100

ExamFees      500        500       500         550     600

Bookfees      200        200       300         300     300

How shall i Do like this format? can any one tell me the solution Of this?
plz.. Thanks in advance..

Comment: Is it related to Database or application ? Do you need schema for the DB

Comment: yes! it s related to database.... i dont know about schema..

Answer (score 0):

If you have `database` in place, easiest way is to use

[**Linq To Sql**](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/05/19/using-linq-to-sql-part-1.aspx) or [**Entity Framework**](http://www.asp.net/learn/3.5-SP1/video-245.aspx)

If this is not the case and and you are starting from scratch, better look at these tutorials. They will help you to come up with a working application in a day or two.

- [**Data Access Tutorials**](http://www.asp.net/learn/data-access/)

Comment: i didnt experience about linq and EntityFramework...
Can you tell me exactly or can you tell me another way to to solve this problem?

Comment: Just go through these tutorials. you will understand how it works. It is is easier than you think. I recommended above because it will create automatically `Data Access Layer` for your application., saving you time and fuss about where to start from. Also check the answer again. includes start-up tutorials link